# How to replace '(' , ')' using sub in R?

Tags: regex, r

How to replace `(` , `)` using sub in R ?

Let define `x` as :

```
x="abc(def"
```

then when I try to replace `(` by something else the error occur :

```
sub("(","",x)
```

the error is :

`'Missing ')''`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need escape:

```
> sub("\\(", "@", x)
[1] "abc@def"
```

Answer (score 12):

As Kohske said you need double escape, but you can also use the argument `fixed=TRUE`:

```
sub("\\(","",x)
sub("(","",x,fixed=TRUE)
```

Both give you:

```
[1] "abcdef"
```